# JavaScript for loops inside of setInterval for Collision Detection?

Tags: javascript, canvas, for-loop, collision-detection, setinterval

I am currently making a Space Invaders remake in JavaScript, and my animating and such has been going pretty great, up until now.

You see I have a `Object` called `Alien` that holds a single aliens data. Every time an Alien is created it is added to an array of aliens, name `aliens`, respectively. I also have a `Object` called a `Shot`, which holds the info on a `Shot` from the player. `Shot` calls a `setInterval` method on itself, which allows it to update and automagically move up the screen. I figure the best place to do collision detection calls would be in here, as I'll have access to the variables that are relevant.

JavaScript does not seem to like it though. For example I have this code as my auto-updating animation:

```
this.draw = function(shot){
    board.fillStyle = "black";
    board.fillRect(shot.x - 1, shot.y + 1, shot.img.width+2,shot.img.height+2);
    shot.y -= 1; 
    if(shot.y < -5){
        clearInterval(shot.shooting);
    }
    board.drawImage(shot.img, shot.x, shot.y); 

    if(isCollidingWithAlien(shot)){
        //Do Collision Detectiony Stuffs
    }
};
```

The code near the end though, `if(isCollidingWithAlien(shot))...` never seems to be run, as I've tested many times with different `console.log` statements.

Do you know why it isn't being run/how to fix this behaviour?

Here is the `isCollidingWithAlien` code:

```
var isCollidingWithAlien = function(shot){
    for(var i = 0; i < aliens; i++){
        return intersects(
            shot.x, 
            shot.y, 
            shot.img.width, 
            shot.img.height, 
            aliens[i].x, 
            aliens[i].y, 
            document.getElementById("alien").width, 
            document.getElementById("alien").height);
    }
};
```

And here is the Collision Detection code:

```
// returns true if there is any overlap
// params: x,y,w,h of two rectangles
function intersects(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2) {
    w2 += x2;
    w1 += x1;
    if (x2 > w1 || x1 > w2) 
        return false;
    h2 += y2;
    h1 += y1;
    if (y2 > h1 || y1 > h2) 
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Here is a **JSFiddle** to see it all in action:
[**JSFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/LPdyx/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a broken for statement.

Replace `aliens` with `aliens.length`

```
for (var i = 0; i < aliens.length; i++) {
        console.log("isCollidingWithAlien");
        return intersects(
        shot.x,
        shot.y,
        shot.img.width,
        shot.img.height,
        aliens[i].x,
        aliens[i].y,
        document.getElementById("alien").width,
        document.getElementById("alien").height);
}
```

I verified that the console is being logged to.

Comment: Hey, this is not my original question, but with the added code you have supplied, `intersects()` never returns true. Do you know why that is? JSFiddle to illustrate: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LPdyx/2/)

Comment: If you are still having this issue, make into a new question.

Comment: Nah it's all working now. You can check out my 'product' [**here**](https://googledrive.com/host/0Bz8X2HNiBM1UaFctcHdfLWItdjg/res/Games/SpaceInvaders/spaceInvaders.html)